# Hawking radiation and black hole entropy

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, qft-in-curved-spacetime, black-hole-thermodynamics

Is black hole entropy, computed by means of quantum field theory on curved spacetime, the entropy of matter degrees of freedom i.e. non-gravitational dofs? What is one actually counting?

Comment: There is no agreement about the origin of BH entropy. You can get the Bekenstein-Hawking result —or at least the "area law"— by means of different ways. See here http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bekenstein-Hawking_entropy#What_is_behind_the_black_hole_entropy

Comment: why is one not just considering all kinds of field dofs? That would probably take a theory of quantum gravity I guess??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't. This is a mysterious thing in quantum field theory on curved space, as first noted by 't Hooft. If you assume there is a certain amount of entropy in the quantum fields surrounding the black hole, due to their thermal nature, you might estimate that there is a local contribution to the entropy from each approximate mode at the correct local Hawking temperature of the black hole.

This entropy is *divergent* in quantum fields in curved space, because the time dilation factor makes it that at a fixed energy, the number of modes diverges as you approach the horizon. This is one of the paradoxes that led t'Hooft to the holographic principle.

Within AdS/CFT models, it is easy to give an answer-- the entropy of a black hole is the entropy of it's CFT description. This includes systems like stacked branes, in which case, the entropy of the black hole is the number of vacuum states. This is Strominger and Vafa's famous calculation of 1995-96. This entropy coincides with the extremal horizon area (although in this case, the black hole is extremal, so the temperature is zero).

Within string theory, this mystery is essentially resolved. The entropy is the entropy of the microscopic constituents of the black hole. It is not resolvable in curved-space QFT because of the 't Hooft divergence, and it is not well resolved in an agreed upon manner in any other approach (this means loops).

Comment: String theory is not able to compute the entropy of 4-dimensional Schwarzschild or Kerr BH. Or is there any recent progress? Wald computed the BH entropy as the Noether charge under diff. in 1993.

Comment: By the way, just a minor thing: 't Hooft instead of t'Hooft.

Comment: So the picture that String theory gives, is less clear and complete than mostly stated?

Comment: @drake: I agree that there is no analytical computation, but there is no absolutely no doubt that if you sat down and counted microstates you would get the right answer. This is not true of other approaches. I don't know the Wald thing, but it is not possible to do it from his methods in '93 by counting states, just by doing formal identifications. From guessing, it's probably just identifying the natural periodicity of imaginary time in the diff group of the exterior, and making some formal trick. It can't be real entropy, like in strings.

Comment: @Hamurabi: I don't get it--- I thought I said it's complete and clear.

Comment: You state, that it is resolved in a agreed upon manner in ST. drake writes, that ST cannot compute the BH entropy for Schwarzschild BHs. Is this true? If this is true, then it is certainly not complete and clear.

Comment: @Hamurabi: It's not _complete_ and clear, but it's clear that it would come out right (this is hard to justify, but everyone agrees now)--- the reason is that it comes out right in the extremal case, and in the near extremal case it comes out wrong by a factor which is understood to come from the difference in strong-coupling/weak-coupling limit. So people made predictions about gauge theories from this, and they work (although I don't think the exact factor is proved yet). So while the calculation has not been done, we can do it on a computer in principle, and we are pretty sure it will work.

Comment: That looks promising, but what does this mean: "the calculation has not been done, we can do it on a computer in principle, and we are pretty sure it will work."?? What are the difficulties? If you know technical details, it would be nice if you could name them. I am really curious...

Comment: @Hamurabi: It means nobody has proved it, but people are sure it will come out right, just like nobody has strictly proved that equipartition works, or that the infrared problem in QED doesn't lead to blowups. This is one of the things that makes physics different from mathematics--- sometimes you acquire certainty by roundabout routes. The difficult part is formulating the entropy as measured at infinity precisely--- the exact descriptions are near horizon, and they need to be matched to far away. This is the major semi-solved problem of 1990-2000, it's most of this literature.

Comment: do you have any good review at hand that you can recommend? thank you

Comment: @Hamurabi: I am sorry, unfortunately, no. I can point you to one of the greatest of all papers: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9601029 . This derived the Bekenstein Hawking entropy for a class of extremal black holes. Those citing this one extend this, I forget the other references.

Comment: thank you! but i am already not so happy with the abstract: 
"The Bekenstein-Hawking area-entropy relation SBH = A/4 is derived for a class of five-dimensional extremal black holes in string theory by counting the degeneracy of BPS soliton bound states." i am not really into string theory. extra dimensions seem to be needed for consistency, not being a solution of the theory. to use this concept then to argue about black holes... i should read the paper before complaining.

Answer (score 1):

There are a multiplicity of ways of deriving the Hawking formula for black hole entropy.  Some techniques, like Bekenstein's argument, do equate the entropy of matter falling into the hole with the entropy of the hole.  Some actually count gravitational microstates in various quantum gravity schema.  The result $S\propto A$ seems to be quite generic in all of these approaches, however, at least to the first order of approximation in $\hbar$ (I believe the LQG result has $\mathbb{O}(\hbar^{2})$ corrections to the Hawking formula).

Comment: Bekenstein's argument is heuristic, it doesn't actually equate the entropy of the infalling matter to the black hole, it just uses the second law and the arbitrariness of the infalling matter to get a good understanding of what the Black hole entropy should be.

Comment: This is not really true--- you get $S = cA + b$, where b is sometimes a huge constant, and c depends on adjustible parameters in LQG, last I looked (I didn't look too hard).

Comment: @ronmaimon : I'm citing this from a seminar a long time ago.  I know that Ashtekar has a paper deriving the Hawking formula, and the result is that you get the Hawking formula to first order, and then there are higher order corrections.  And I don't see where the contradiction with what I said about the Bekenstein bound is--you talk abuout lowering mass into the BH in a way that minimizes entropy gain, you lose the mass in the horizon, and then note that $S\propto A$.

Comment: I agree, but the constant is not determined, and the entropy is not in the object once it dissolves into the black hole, and OP's question is, "where is it?"

Comment: it is not really true anymore in LQG. There have been calculations with $S\sim\frac{A}{4\ell_p^2}$ plus baggage of $\mathcal{O}(\hbar)$, recently.

Comment: In the LQG calculation, as far as I know,  one counts the number of DOF on the horizon so it is not a great achievement to get the "area law". The result is finite but depends on the Immirzi parameter (an ambiguity in the quantization) so one uses this result to fix the Immirzi parameter. Moreover there is a logarithmic correction to the semiclassical result. The pro is that this is done for a realistic astrophysical BH such us Schwarchilzd.

Comment: i guess it is not overall too surprising that the entropy is proportional to the area, in either way. i shoudl calculate the entropy of a thin surface of harmonic oscialltors and will probably get the same. maybe even a 2d ideal gas has it.

Comment: as i have written in lqg currently above the immirzi parameter disappears in the first term. it gives altogether $S\sim A+logA+\hbar f(\gamma)$, where $f(\gamma)$ is a function of the immirzi parameter $\gamma$. apparently one is counting the dofs of the quantum gravitational field of the horizon. not the matter dofs.